# SWIFTUI List want to have toggle in a list. Cannot convert value of type 'MyModel' to expected argument type 'Binding<MyModel>'

Tags: swift, list, binding, swiftui, state

I simply want to have al list of records with a text and a toggle. Somehow I don't get it at all.I get the error: Cannot convert value of type 'MyModel' to expected argument type 'Binding'

How can I get the bool value shown in the list as a toggle and being changeable?

This my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var myModels: [MyModel] = [
       MyModel(id: "1", name: "First Model-1-", notify: false),
       MyModel(id: "2", name: "Second Model", notify: true)
   ]

var body: some View {

    List{
        ForEach(myModels, id: \.id){myModel in
            HStack{
            Text(myModel.name)
            Spacer()
            ToggleView(myModel: myModel) //<-- here s the error message: Cannot convert value of type 'MyModel' to expected argument type 'Binding<MyModel>'
        }
        }

}
}

}



struct ToggleView: View {
@Binding var myModel: MyModel // <<

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Toggle(isOn: $myModel.notify) {
            Text("Done")
        }
        Text(myModel.notify ? "Complete" : "Not complete")

    }
}
}
```

Any help is more than appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you just need to use a two way binding. So a $ is missing:

```
ToggleView(myModel: $myModel)
```

Comment: thx for your comment, but this does not work either. myModel is from the "ForEach" and does not have a binding ..(myModels , with the "s" at the end, has @State binding) I used the struct ToggleView in order to get from bool to Binding<bool>, but I guess this is not the right way